# How do I get a button to trigger a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have a C#/.NET web application I am working on. On one of the pages I have a table of values generated from a database. I need each value to be clickable so that when you click a value it filters data in a separate table next to it.

So what I decided to do was to make each value into a button:

```
<input type="button" id="exampleID" class="exampleClass" value="@Model.Data.Value1" />
```

In my Javascript I have this:

```
$(".exampleClass").click(function () {...
```

The code inside the function isn't relevant to the question because it isn't getting called when I click the button. Each button has a unique ID that I am using in my function and I gave them each the same class so that I can catch when any of them are called and then use their unique ID to determine which was clicked. I have set a breakpoint inside the function using Firebug but it's not getting tripped when I click the button. I am stumped as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Is the above javascript inside a document.ready handler?

Comment: Like @Archer said, look into the document.ready handler. Also, you can avoid other problems with elements that are created after the JavaScript runs by forming your code this way: `$(document).on('click', '.exampleClass', function () { ... })`

Comment: No it is not. I'll try that.

Comment: @Saliceran That'll be why.  Either of the above suggestions (or putting the script at the end of the page) should work.

Comment: Why do people always forget this. Isn't it the first thing shown in every jQuery tutorial?

Comment: Didn't get to see the comments before I posted my answer. @Barmar, I totally agree. The jQuery team should make t-shirts: Got `document.ready()`?

Comment: Putting it in a `document.ready()` function did nothing. The buttons are in a partial that is loaded by the main razor code that has the javascript in it. Could that be affecting it?

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of things: are you attaching the `click` event in the `ready` method? Is jQuery even loaded on the page? Have you tried refining the selector? For example, `$('input.exampleClass').click()`. It has to be some dumb mistake.